# New-ADUser : The object name has bad syntax. Powershell Docx import error

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to create new Active Directory users from a word document. However I am running into a problem during creation of the user wherein the script says "The object name has Bad Syntax" I have narrowed down the problem to the "New-ADUser:" portion of the code below

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module activedirectory
  
#Create word application object
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

#Assign document path
$documentPath = Read-host => [Enter Template to use Ex:"C:\Users\username\Desktop\employeeform.docx"]

#open the document
$document = $word.Documents.Open($documentPath)

#list all tables in doc
$document.Tables | ft

#get info from a certain part of the table

$pager = $document.Tables[1].Cell(4,2).range.text
$fname = $document.Tables[1].Cell(6,2).range.text
$lname = $document.Tables[1].Cell(8,2).range.text
$fn1 = $fname.Substring(0,1)
$username = "$fn1$lname"
$jobtitle = $document.Tables[1].Cell(15,2).range.text
$department = $document.Tables[1].Cell(16,2).range.text
$manager = $document.Tables[1].Cell(17,2).range.text
$pagernumber = $pager.Substring(17)
$template = Read-host => [Enter Template to use Ex:MedicalAssistant]
#folder = $User.folder 

Write-Output $documentPath
Write-Output $template






   
    

#Check to see if the user already exists in AD
if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $username})
{
     #If user does exist, give a warning
     Write-Warning "A user account with username $username already exist in Active Directory."
         pause
}
else
{
    #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account 
      
    New-ADUser `
    -SamAccountName $username `
    -Name "$fname $lname" `
    -GivenName $fname `
    -Surname $lname `
    -Enabled $True `
    -DisplayName "$lname $fname" `
    -Company "Companyname" `
    -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring "Password" -AsPlainText -Force)`
    -HomeDrive "X:" `
    -ScriptPath "K32.exe" `
    -OtherAttributes @{pager=$pagernumber} `
    -Title $jobtitle `
    -Department $department `
    -Description $jobtitle `
    #-Manager $manager `  
   #-HomeDirectory $folder `

            
    }

#Close the document
$document.close()

#Close Word
$word.Quit()


pause
```

After searching google it seems this problem occurred because of how I am importing the document into the script which makes the variables objects instead of strings but I am unsure of how else to import the document so that the variable imports as a string. I attempted to use  | Out-String and this did not change my error message, so google may have led me astray.

Comment: Can you post the error as plain text? Also, what does `$username.GetType().FullName` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the variables you read from the table are trimmed and not empty ($null).

Better recreate that table into a CSV where you have much more control over the data and don't have to fiddle with the Word.Application COM object.

Also I would recommend using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1) the parameters to New-ADUser, so you can get rid of using all those nasty backticks (which will give you errors when there is anything other than a newline following it..)

```
$userProps = @{
    SamAccountName  = $username
    Name            = "$fname $lname"
    GivenName       = $fname
    Surname         = $lname
    Enabled         = $True
    DisplayName     = "$lname $fname"
    Company         = "Companyname"
    AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force)
    HomeDrive       = "X:"
    ScriptPath      = "K32.exe"
    OtherAttributes = @{pager=$pagernumber}
    Title           = $jobtitle
    Department      = $department
    Description     = $jobtitle
    # Manager       = $manager
    # HomeDirectory = $folder
}

New-ADUser @userProps
```

Comment: I am still fairly new to Power Shell and Splatting is amazing! Thank you for introducing me to that. The backticks were hell to work with. Also I will be converting the word table into an CSV  document as the CSV is way easier to work with. Thank you for your help!